# Woocommerce reviews xss issue

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, security, review

I enabled reviews on my woocommerce website and I see that I can insert html / js code in the review comments.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: not to use it? anyway, it might be that something else is braking it on your site

Comment: I have this problem even if I use a fresh wordpress install with no plugins (only woocommerce). So, am I the only one who has this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and disable WooCommerce and comment on a post; you can do the same thing because you're logged in as admin. Admin users are able to post unfiltered content. If you repeat the test logged out, you'll notice you're not able to exploit anything.

See this trac ticket from WordPress https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33402

And this article on make.wordpress https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-security-vulnerabilities/#why-are-some-users-allowed-to-post-unfiltered-html

For future reference, please report security issues responsibly rather than publicly - use https://hackerone.com/automattic

Comment: hmmm, I am far from being the most knowledgeable person about security, but if an admin can post anything with no nonce verification, that it is a possible XSS vector. The fact that it is the way core behaves (if it actually is like that) is no excuse for other software. Nonce should (almost ?) always be used with logged in users

Comment: ... so hopefully the proper answer here is that there is nonce verification and therefor the admin can not be tricked to post broken HTML that might break his site, and if he decided to put some unlikely html in the site, if he actually meant it, there is no problem with it as he is the admin after all and should be able to do whatever he wants.